# Is it correct to say "news besides someplace"?

Tags: word-usage

It is for site name, so therefore quite minimal meaningful phrases.

which option is more acceptable?

1. news besides Canada
2. besides news Canada
3. news beside Canada
4. beside news Canada

Meaning of the phrase should be at least a little mean "news Canada", "news about Canada", "addition to news about Canada"

Comment: Your examples seem to be about news from everywhere _except_ Canada. Is that what you are trying to convey?

Comment: I'm not sure if *beside* or *besides* is the right word for you. *Beside(s)* gives me an idea that your news is not about Canada. Even saying "in addition to news about Canada" still sounds like news about everything else but Canada itself. Because you said No, perhaps you might mean that your news is not the main news. Perhaps you could coin a term *sidenews*, similar to *sidebar*, *side dish*, *side menu*, or *sidewalk*.

Comment: And once again - thank you.
Given my poor English, I decided to use the most neutral word of those that I know - "ANY".
I hope "anylocalnews.com" domain name sounds more or less well to the English ear.

Comment: I think we need more context in order to help you meaningfully... :-)

Comment: I think we need more context to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Besides* and *Beside* are two different words.

> [Besides](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/BESIDES) (adv, preposition) - making an additional point or in addition to/apart from. 
>   [Beside](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/beside) (preposition0 - next to, at the side of (also used when you compare)

That way, all the examples won't serve the purpose. For instance, *news beside Canada* may mean *News (sitting) beside Canada?*.

If you are searching for the available domain names, you may additionally put words like 'online', 'click for', 'on the net' and the like. Putting meaningful words in URL will also help you getting an extra mileage in [SEO](http://moz.com/learn/seo/url).

Comment: Besides = "in addition to". Can not you say "in addition to news about Canada" i.e. "news besides Canada"?

Comment: @user3278440 It'll be then *news, besides the news from Canada.*

Comment: @MaulikV +1, but also "besides the news from Canada" is unwieldy. Maybe "news from outside Canada"? I think we need more information about what the OP tends to convey. Are they situated in Canada and want to additionally present news from outside Canada, for example?